# Elasticsearch shard relocation query - is the master node involved during shard relocation (data transfer)

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, we have one master node running on master1
two data nodes running on server2, server3

Let us say shard relocation happening from server2 to server3

Now to copy the data folder, will elasticsearch cluster make use of master1 (which is a master node) i.e. is the data transferred directly from server2 to server3 or will it go via master1?

We would like to know this as our master1 is running low configuration machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the master node is not directly involved in the transfer of shards from one node to another. The data is copied from the source node directly to the destination node.

The master node is involved in managing global cluster state, but if it's master only it will not have any data files on it nor have data transferred to or from it:

> Note, Elasticsearch is a peer to peer based system, nodes communicate
>   with one another directly if operations are delegated / broadcast. All
>   the main APIs (index, delete, search) do not communicate with the
>   master node. The responsibility of the master node is to maintain the
>   global cluster state, and act if nodes join or leave the cluster by
>   reassigning shards.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html

> dedicated master nodes are nodes with the settings node.data: false
>   and node.master: true. We actively promote the use of dedicated master
>   nodes in critical clusters to make sure that there are 3 dedicated
>   nodes whose only role is to be master, a lightweight operational
>   (cluster management) responsibility. By reducing the amount of
>   resource intensive work that these nodes do (in other words, do not
>   send index or search requests to these dedicated master nodes), we
>   greatly reduce the chance of cluster instability.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html

Comment: Thanks John, the things are clear. We understand where the issue was. Shards relocation took so much time for us as gave 100mb as the transfer rate but that cause issue as all the nodes are trying to utilize 100mb, when we changed that to 25mb it worked fine.

Comment: @KumarD Can you tell me what the issue is clearly, 100mb and 25mb setting.. What setting is that and how did making it 25mb made it much better. Thank you.